# ZF2 best practice to change core classes of the vendor module?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I did read this answer [ZF2, what's the best practice for working with Vendor Module's Form classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783873/zf2-whats-the-best-practice-for-working-with-vendor-modules-form-classes). So it's mainly clear how to change configurable parts of the vendor module, but what do I do if in zfcUser module I want to add new functionality to the Entity/User?

In short I want to check user role, I've added to DB field, what's the best way to do that? Maybe I should do it somewhere else and not in zfcUSer if so where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't be claiming this is a best practice, but this is how I managed to handle the situation!
First - big thanks to answer in this question [ZF2: Custom user mapper for ZfcUser module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186809/zf2-custom-user-mapper-for-zfcuser-module).

So, I did:

1. Added configuration of `zfcUser/Entity` in `zfc-user.global.php` autoload:

   ```
   'zfcuser' => array(
       'tableName' => 'users',
       'user_entity_class' => 'Application\Entity\User'
   ),
   ```
2. Added my classes for `Entity\User`, `Mapper\User` and `Mapper\Hydrator` into my `src/Application` Entity and Mapper subfolders.
3. Updated those classes namespaces to be my `Application\Entity` and `Application\Mapper`
4. Added this configuration to `getServiceConfig` function of my `Module.php`:

   ```
   'factories' => [
       'zfcuser_user_mapper' => function ($sm) {
           $mapper = new Mapper\User();
           $mapper->setDbAdapter($sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'));
           $mapper->setEntityPrototype(new Entity\User());
           $mapper->setHydrator(new Mapper\UserHydrator());
           return $mapper;
       },
   ]
   ```
5. Updated my classes dependencies to use `ZfcUSer` and started my `Entity\User` as `extends \ZfcUser\Entity\User implements \ZfcUser\Entity\UserInterface`.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at `ZfcUser/config/zfcuser.global.php.dist`

In there you'll see this

```
/**
 * User Model Entity Class
 *
 * Name of Entity class to use. Useful for using your own entity class
 * instead of the default one provided. Default is ZfcUser\Entity\User.
 * The entity class should implement ZfcUser\Entity\UserInterface
 */
//'user_entity_class' => 'ZfcUser\Entity\User',
```

The directions are straightforward, copy the file to `./config/autoload/zfcuser.global.php`, makes sure your entity class implements the `ZfcUser\Entity\UserInterface`, uncomment that line and change the FQCN to match the entity you want to use instead.

Comment: But topic continues. What if I want to use column name "id" not "user_id" or changing any other file that can not be set in config? BTW even if I change the entity via config, where is the best place to store my custom UserEntity? Thanks!

Comment: If you wanted to used different column names you'd swap out the zfcuser_user_mapper service for one of your own. Typically, you'd do this in your own module and supply the classes and config to over-ride zfcusers settings and services in there.

Comment: Hm, could you point to the code sample please? I'm really new to ZF2 ways :). Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to find any good examples. Check out the zfcuser wiki https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/_pages . Take a look at all the questions on SO that have been asked about zfcuser http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zfcuser+is%3Aquestion . Look at other modules which extend or otherwise interact with zfcuser, such as, zfcUserDoctrineORM found at https://github.com/ZF-Commons or the ScnSocialAuth module at https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth