# ZfcUser custom Database Column names

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

In my database i have a table "myuser". I have "usr_id", "usr_username", "usr_password" etc. fields.

But ZfcUser always try to save "username", "password" etc.

How can i define custom column names for ZfcUser?

I am using Zend/DB/Tablegateway

Comment: are u using doctrine or tablegateway?

Comment: i am using Zend/Db/tablegateway

Comment: possible duplicate of [ZF2: Custom user mapper for ZfcUser module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186809/zf2-custom-user-mapper-for-zfcuser-module)